# Ansible is not picking up installed hvac module after installing on mac OS

Tags: ansible

My ansible play uses `hashivault_read`. I installed this module on my mac. When I try to execute the playbook, this task errors out saying `No module named hvac`. When I see `pip list` I can find this module on my mac.

Did anyone face this issue before on mac? If someone has a resolution to this please comment.

Ansible Properties

```
ansible-playbook 2.8.0
  config file = /Users/mdhoke/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/Users/mdhoke/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 2.7.10 (default, Feb 22 2019, 21:55:15) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.37.14)]
```

I assume ansible is trying to find `hvac` module under `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ansible` which is not present but `hashivault_read` is present. 
`hvac` module is present under `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`.

Error I am getting:

```
fatal: [vault]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to vault closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/home/mdhoke/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1567120470.9-210430890667193/AnsiballZ_hashivault_read.py\", line 114, in <module>\r\n    _ansiballz_main()\r\n  File \"/home/mdhoke/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1567120470.9-210430890667193/AnsiballZ_hashivault_read.py\", line 106, in _ansiballz_main\r\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\r\n  File \"/home/mdhoke/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1567120470.9-210430890667193/AnsiballZ_hashivault_read.py\", line 49, in invoke_module\r\n    imp.load_module('__main__', mod, module, MOD_DESC)\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_hashivault_read_payload_kE0iQk/__main__.py\", line 3, in <module>\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_hashivault_read_payload_kE0iQk/ansible_hashivault_read_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/hashivault.py\", line 4, in <module>\r\n

ImportError: No module named hvac\r\n", 

"msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `hashivault_read` module is expected to be executed on a local machine. So delegating it to local machine solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this issue for myself yesterday.  I assume you are running ansible locally from your mac and connecting to the remote server (vault).  If so, you will need to install hvac on the vault server too.

the following code snippet will suffice

```
- name: install hvac pip package
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  pip:
    name: hvac
    state: present
```

obviously for the above play to work, you will need python-pip installed on the vault server too and in order to install that, you will need to enable epel-release.  The below coe will take care of those dependencies.

```
- name: enable epel-relase and install pip
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  yum:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: present
  with_items:
    - epel-release
    - python-pip
```

Comment: I should add that the above code examples are written for CentOS / Redhat.  You will need to adjust the plays accordingly for debian based distros etc